# Webpack with angular 1.4 ES 5

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, gulp, ecmascript-5

I am working on an application which is build with angular 1.4 and ES5. It is using gulp to minify files. I wanted to use Webpack to leverage features like code-splitting and bundling everything in JavaScript files.

Is it even possible to use webpack with ES5 code as I see almost all blogs about WebPack deal with ES6. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

[This is how my team did it](https://brian.olore.net/wp/2018/01/build-angularjs-without-editing-thousands-of-files-journey-webpack-part-7/). Essentially you want to create "entry point files" that perform `require`s for all your files, since this is how webpack works (it follows the dependency tree). Then point webpack at these "entry point files".

The example at the link above uses TypeScript, but you can easily use ES5 like this:

```
# ./entry-points/feature1.js
importAll = function(r) {
  r.keys().forEach(r);
};

importAll(require.context('./app/feature1', true, /module\.js$/));
importAll(require.context('./app/feature1', true, /(^(?!.*(spec|module)\.js).*\.js)$/));
```

You can grab a polyfill for `Object.keys` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and Array.forEach` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Then point to this file from your webpack config like this:

```
entry: {
  'feature1': './entry-points/feature1.js'
}
```